# Stretch a div to it's full width

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I'm using bootstrap classes and div to make the 2 divs as shown below in the picture. The upper div, the one with icons is not stretching till the end of the screen as with the lower div. What Am I doing wrong? Also, Please note that in any circumstances I have to keep my icons in the middle of the div like they are as of now. This is my CSS and HTML Code:

CSS:

```
.icons_div
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: max-content;
}

.icon
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 15px;
  display: initial;
}

.fa
{
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="icons_div">
        <div class="row bg-secondary">
            <div class="col-sm-2"> 
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </div> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> </div> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i> </div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-dark" style="height: 40px;"></div>
    </div>
</div> <br> <br>
```

P.S I have already imported all the neccesary Bootstrap 4 libraries, so that's not an issue

[image: My program output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the whole styling of `.icons_div` class. `max-content` adjust the width of the div depending on the content inside the div. So it is making the div smaller. Also add `row` class to the div having `icons_div` class.

```
<div class="row icons_div">
```

Learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: That did the job thanx, But What I want is to shift the icons in the middle of the div, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not sure why people upvoted. `content` is invalid value so what has actually done is that the browser does not apply css `width`. So simple solution should be remove `width: max-content`

Comment: Also try to change `display: initial` to `display: table` to align icons to middle